# getting error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java300.dll

Tags: java, opencv, servlets

I am running a servlet program to read an image using opencv,
getting error  :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java300.dll already loaded in another classloader . When restarting the IDE it works fine.
```

I loaded `System.loadLibrary ( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ) ;`  in servlet only ones.

Can anybody suggest a solution for how to unload it. And also anybody know how to read an image from browser using opencv in java.?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the library is not in the system path, it needs to first added to the system path, then load. First extract the OpenCV to C drive something like this `c:\opencv\...` then use this code below to during initializing, it will automatically load the OpenCV lib in windows environment.

```
public static void loadOpenCV_Lib() throws Exception {
    String model = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    String libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x86/";
    if(model.equals("64")) {
        libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x64/";
    }
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", libraryPath);
    Field sysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    sysPath.setAccessible(true);
    sysPath.set(null, null);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

And also it will automatically detect the system model and load the lib according to the system model.

Comment: I already added this code to my init()  method as per your suggestion. But when i run it, showing error :  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java300.dll already loaded in another classloader.  When i restart the IDE, it works fine without editing. can u give any suggestion for this error.

Comment: And do u know  how to read an image from browser using opencv in java.?

Comment: What IDE you are using?

Comment: You can read image data to bytes, then convert byte array to Mat object, in Servlet you can do it by uploading file to server

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Hi Adil, Do you have any idea about the error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java300.dll already loaded in another classloader ??

Comment: One thing that I will ask is that; did you load the lib by Netbeans it self, for example in Eclipse you load the OpenCV lib by setting the configuration of the project, if in Netbeans is the same then, do not load by IDE it self, just use the code above. I want to know this first.

Comment: Did you mean setting the path to .dll file when configuring as C:\opencv\build\java\x64 ?? I alredy set it in netbeans . Now i removed it and checked. Still showing the same error. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java300.dll already loaded in another classloader.

Comment: Yes. The problem maybe of the loading lib will done twice. One is from IDE one is done by your self. You can check. It what that I can guess.

Comment: I checked by removing it. but still shows the same error.